# JW player - Change position of poster image to display before video starts

Tags: jwplayer

I am using jw player for playing videos on my site. Here is screen shot for it,

[image]

Is there is any way to change the height , width and position of circled play image?

Here is my script for jw player,

```
player = jwplayer("videoplayer-embed").setup({
         "flashplayer": "js/player.swf",
        "image": "tempvideo/videoPreview.jpg",
        "controlbar": "bottom",
        "skin": "{% static 'videoskin/ysm_fb_skin.xml' %}",
        "width": 600,
        "height": 748,
                "playlist":[
                            {file:'url', title:"", caption:"",
                            },
                ]
        });
```

Comment: do you have link where you run this? what version of jwplayer you use?

Comment: This doesn't even look like the JW Player. By default, the image should fill the entire display. Going to need to see a link here.

Comment: @Ben I am using jw player verison 5.10.2295.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Trust me it is jw player I am using custom skin for it , Here is [link](http://flyerboard-dev.medicine.yale.edu/multimedia/video/Media%20Library%20Videos/1/3/?index=1&video=true&width=1320&height=820&site=3)  for it

Comment: This link times out for me, it seems to be an internal page.

Answer (score 0):

Nice skin .. you're using http://flyerboard-dev.medicine.yale.edu/static/videoskin/ysm_fb_skin.xml ?

That is where you would change the display of the icons. Here for example is the playbutton: http://flyerboard-dev.medicine.yale.edu/static/videoskin/controlbar/playButton.png